# CSS columns with equals maximum heights

Tags: css

We are currently working on a project that requires 2 or more columns with equals heights. More specifically, every column has to be the height of maximum column height among them. DIVs are positioned next to each other with `float: left`, and the sum of their widths is exactly 100%. An example can be found in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mj3Ks/1/.

We allow elements within a column to be dragged from one to another. Therefore the height of columns is not fixed and should be updated dynamically. Currently we have implemented a javascript solution that recalculates heights based on dragging and child resizing. However, this solution is quite cumbersome and error prone. Hence, we are looking for a pure css so that the parent has the height of the maximum child element, and every child element has a 100% of its parent. The solution has to be compatible with IE 9+ and any other major browser. I hope anyone can help us.

Comment: Your code forgot to paste

Comment: That really is not that relevant as we are looking for a CSS solution, not JS. For your information:

`parentContainer.find('> .column').css('height', '').height(parentContainer.height());`

which happens on resize/dragging of one of the child elements within a container

Comment: The markup is basically as in this fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj3Ks/1/). All columns should have the height of the heighest column, but the number of columns is dynamic (as is their content)

Answer (score 0):

There's a neat CSS hack to do what you're trying to do, but in general it is difficult without CSS.

firstly, we need to add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

onto the parent div.

Then, the good bit, on the child divs add

```
margin-bottom: -100%;
padding-bottom: 100%;
```

This does mean that you lose the bottom border in your current code, so I remedied that by adding a border bottom to the container.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/nZDTW/

Source: http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61